# Latex multiple equations

Tags: equations, align

I want to make something like this but i don't know how, please help me.

[image: Multiple equations]

Comment: Do you mean that with the black angled border, or is that an artifact of your cropping?

Comment: If the border you show is desired, then `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3pt}}|}
$\begin{aligned}
 (p+q)(x+y) &= M\\
 x+y &= 16
\end{aligned}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (p+q)(x+y)&=M\\
x+y&=16
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

See the amsmath package documentation for lots more examples.